# How to get size of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

[image]

How do you get the size this object? I want to loop through each object within the parent object.

Comment: How you define size? number of properties? Is that just in the top-level object or do you need to descend into child properties? does it include prototype properties? Or are you interested in the amount of memory that the object retains?

Answer (score 4):

To count the number of owned properties:

```
Object.keys(users).length
```